# Firebase API-created user can't sign in with email link with disableSignUp status true

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, firebase-admin

- I need to create users server-side using Firebase Admin.
- I disallow signups using Firebaseui with `disableSignUp` status set to `true`.
- I wish to use email link sign in only.

When I create the user (in Python) using

```
auth.create_user(email=email, display_name=name, photo_url=profile_image_url)
```

a user is created but the user has no `providerData` and is shown the message:

```
newuser@example.com is not authorized to view the requested page.
```

That's unexpected - the Firebaseui documentation says that users can be created through the API and one would expect such users to be able to log in!

When I create the user as above but with a password, they are allowed to log in but they are shown a password prompt.

How can I create a new email user and force email link sign in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already have a cloud function to notify users that their account has been created. I added

```
  var actionCodeSettings = {
    url: 'https://example.com/welcome',
    handleCodeInApp: true,
  };  

  const link =  await admin.auth().generateSignInWithEmailLink(user.email, actionCodeSettings);
```

to the function, and they now get a link to complete their account setup. Landing on '/welcome' opens the `firebaseui-auth-container` where the message "Confirm your email to complete sign in" is shown. The email is confirmed, and the user is changed to an `emailLink` user. It's a quite natural flow, almost as if it was designed for that purpose...